# How to save and bind Camel dynamic route and Quartz scheduler in DB and restore it after application restart?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-camel

There is a Springboot application that receives the parameters (what, where) of the route (Apache Camel) and the schedule for its execution (Quartz).
For example, log a message every second, or send a message to the ActiceMQ queue once.
A database is used to save and restore the schedule in case of an application restart.

How to correctly save and restore Apache Camel route parameters on application restart by linking it to its corresponding schedule?

```
public class CustomRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    private final int repeatInterval;
    private final String message;
    private final String destination;
    private final String triggerName;

    public CustomRouter(
            int repeatInterval, 
            String message, 
            String destination, 
            String triggerName) {
        this.repeatInterval = repeatInterval;
        this.message = message;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.triggerName = triggerName;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("customQuartz://" 
                + triggerName + "?trigger.repeatInterval=" + repeatInterval)
                .setBody(simple(this.message))
                .to(destination);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CamelStarter implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
    
    private final QuartzComponent customQuartz;
    private DefaultCamelContext camelCustomContext;

    public CamelStarter(QuartzComponent customQuartz) {
        this.customQuartz = customQuartz;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        camelCustomContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelCustomContext.addComponent("customQuartz", customQuartz);
        camelCustomContext.setName("camelCustomContext");
        
        camelCustomContext.addRoutes(new CustomRouter(
                1000, 
                "CustomRouter1", 
                "log:customLog1", 
                "customRouterTrigger1"));
        
        camelCustomContext.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        camelCustomContext.stop();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class CamelCustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean customSchedulerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource, QuartzProperties quartzProperties) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());

        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
        factory.setJobFactory(new SpringBeanJobFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Scheduler customScheduler(
            DataSource dataSource, QuartzProperties quartzProperties) {
        return customSchedulerFactory(dataSource, quartzProperties).getScheduler();
    }

    @Bean
    public QuartzComponent customquartz(
            DataSource dataSource,
            QuartzProperties quartzProperties) {
        QuartzComponent component = new QuartzComponent();
        component.setScheduler(customScheduler(dataSource, quartzProperties));
        return component;
    }
}
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schedule_module
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1111
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=CustomClusteredScheduler
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
```

At the 1st launch of the application, the message is displayed in the Log and entries about the route schedule appear in the database:

```
2023-07-25 22:53:04.929  INFO 9928 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleAppApplication         : Starting ScheduleAppApplication using Java 17.0.6 on DESKTOP-6SHGJTA with PID 9928 (C:\work\dev\testsapps\springboot-camel-quartz\schedule-app\target\classes started by baa in C:\work\dev\testsapps\springboot-camel-quartz\schedule-app)
2023-07-25 22:53:04.932  INFO 9928 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleAppApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-25 22:53:05.775  INFO 9928 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-25 22:53:05.902  INFO 9928 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-25 22:53:05.965  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2023-07-25 22:53:05.978  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2023-07-25 22:53:05.978  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2023-07-25 22:53:05.982  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2023-07-25 22:53:05.984  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : JobStoreCMT initialized.
2023-07-25 22:53:05.985  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'customSchedulerFactory' with instanceId 'CustomClusteredScheduler'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

2023-07-25 22:53:05.986  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'customSchedulerFactory' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2023-07-25 22:53:05.986  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2023-07-25 22:53:05.986  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@4d8286c4
2023-07-25 22:53:06.441  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camelCustomContext) is starting
2023-07-25 22:53:06.501  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job Camel_camelCustomContext.customRouterTrigger1 (cron=null, triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is 2023-07-25T22:53:06.464+0300
2023-07-25 22:53:06.510  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:1)
2023-07-25 22:53:06.510  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started route1 (customQuartz://customRouterTrigger1)
2023-07-25 22:53:06.510  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camelCustomContext) started in 173ms (build:3ms init:102ms start:68ms)
2023-07-25 22:53:06.511  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : Starting Quartz scheduler: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@889a8a8
2023-07-25 22:53:06.522  INFO 9928 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler customSchedulerFactory_$_CustomClusteredScheduler started.
2023-07-25 22:53:06.586  INFO 9928 --- [actory_Worker-1] customLog1                               : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: CustomRouter1]
2023-07-25 22:53:06.787  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camel-1) is starting
2023-07-25 22:53:06.788  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:0)
2023-07-25 22:53:06.788  INFO 9928 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camel-1) started in 61ms (build:42ms init:19ms start:0ms)
2023-07-25 22:53:06.793  INFO 9928 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleAppApplication         : Started ScheduleAppApplication in 2.205 seconds (JVM running for 2.508)
2023-07-25 22:53:07.472  INFO 9928 --- [actory_Worker-2] customLog1                               : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: CustomRouter1]
2023-07-25 22:53:08.470  INFO 9928 --- [actory_Worker-3] customLog1                               : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: CustomRouter1]
2023-07-25 22:53:09.469  INFO 9928 --- [actory_Worker-4] customLog1                               : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: CustomRouter1]
2023-07-25 22:53:10.473  INFO 9928 --- [actory_Worker-5] customLog1                               : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: CustomRouter1]
2023-07-25 22:53:11.470  INFO 9928 --- [actory_Worker-6] customLog1                               : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: CustomRouter1]
```

But if stop the application, remove the line with the addition of the route:

```
@Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        camelCustomContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelCustomContext.addComponent("customQuartz", customQuartz);
        camelCustomContext.setName("camelCustomContext");
        
        camelCustomContext.start();
    }
```

and start the application again, then a message is not displayed in the Log:

```
2023-07-25 22:57:11.225  INFO 16864 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'customSchedulerFactory' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.225  INFO 16864 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2023-07-25 22:57:11.225  INFO 16864 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@6778aea6
2023-07-25 22:57:11.603  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camelCustomContext) is starting
2023-07-25 22:57:11.607  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:0)
2023-07-25 22:57:11.607  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camelCustomContext) started in 29ms (build:3ms init:23ms start:3ms)
2023-07-25 22:57:11.610  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : Starting Quartz scheduler: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@23a918c7
2023-07-25 22:57:11.636  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: detected 1 failed or restarted instances.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.636  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "CustomClusteredScheduler"'s failed in-progress jobs.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.645  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: ......Freed 1 acquired trigger(s).
2023-07-25 22:57:11.650  INFO 16864 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler customSchedulerFactory_$_CustomClusteredScheduler started.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.708  WARN 16864 --- [actory_Worker-1] o.a.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob      : Cannot find existing QuartzEndpoint with uri: customQuartz://customRouterTrigger1?trigger.repeatInterval=1000. Creating new endpoint instance.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.717  WARN 16864 --- [actory_Worker-2] o.a.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob      : Cannot find existing QuartzEndpoint with uri: customQuartz://customRouterTrigger1?trigger.repeatInterval=1000. Creating new endpoint instance.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.732  WARN 16864 --- [actory_Worker-3] o.a.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob      : Cannot find existing QuartzEndpoint with uri: customQuartz://customRouterTrigger1?trigger.repeatInterval=1000. Creating new endpoint instance.
2023-07-25 22:57:11.744  INFO 16864 --- [actory_Worker-1] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job Camel_camelCustomContext.customRouterTrigger1 (cron=null, triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is null
2023-07-25 22:57:11.744  INFO 16864 --- [actory_Worker-2] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job Camel_camelCustomContext.customRouterTrigger1 (cron=null, triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is null
2023-07-25 22:57:11.744  INFO 16864 --- [actory_Worker-3] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job Camel_camelCustomContext.customRouterTrigger1 (cron=null, triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is null
2023-07-25 22:57:11.907  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camel-1) is starting
2023-07-25 22:57:11.908  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:0)
2023-07-25 22:57:11.908  INFO 16864 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.21.0 (camel-1) started in 69ms (build:51ms init:18ms start:0ms)
2023-07-25 22:57:11.914  INFO 16864 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleAppApplication         : Started ScheduleAppApplication in 2.054 seconds (JVM running for 2.394)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but how would you like to have scheduler running if you no longer add the route to the camel context?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).